# Is it possible to filter a wireshark trace to see all ports used within the trace?

Tags: networking, wireshark, packet-sniffers

For example, I want to locate all ports used between 1 - 1024 without manually crawling through a 780 packet trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an expression like this as a filter:

```
tcp.port >= 1 && tcp.port <= 1024
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like viewing Statistics > Endpoints and looking at TCP and UDP gives me a list of ports used. If you've got another way to do it I'm all ears.